# Inserir nomes a uma lista dependendo de seu valor

Tags: python, python-3.x, lista

Estou tentando fazer um código de sorteio, o usuário insere o valor a ser doado e o seu nome.

Vamos supor que Bia doe 10 reais, o nome de Bia tem que aparecer 1 vez na lista.
E vamos supor que Samuel doe 30 reais, o nome dele teria que aparecer 3 vezes na lista.

```
Ex: ['Bia', 'Samuel', 'Samuel', 'Samuel']
```

E assim, sucessivamente.

Eu não estou conseguindo separar o nome do usuário em uma lista, ele fica desse jeito no terminal:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

E o meu código está assim:

```
valor = int(input('Digite o valor que você deseja doar: '))
nome = input('Qual o seu nome? ')

if valor == 10:
    total = 1
    totalNome = [nome * 1]
    print('Você vai concorrer {} vez.'.format(total))
elif valor == 20:
    total = 2
    totalNome = [nome * 2]
    print('Você vai concorrer {} vezes.'.format(total))
elif valor == 30:
    total = 3
    totalNome = [nome * 3]
    print('Você vai concorrer {} vezes.'.format(total))

nomes = []
nomes.append(totalNome)
print(nomes)
```

Comment: Olá pessoal, desculpa, já fiz a correção.. Primeira vez usando aqui, ainda estou me familiarizando. Mas já editei e coloquei como pediram!

Comment: @hkotsubo eu não tinha me atentado quanto a isso, posso usar o random.shuffle na lista nomes mesmo, né?

Comment: Eu quero fazer o seguinte, vamos supor que Samuel doou 40 reais. O nome de Samuel tem que aparecer 4 vezes na lista. Se Bia doou 20, o nome dela tem que aparecer 2 vezes. Eu preciso listar alguns "doadores" com suas respectivas doações. Pra fazer um sorteio com essas pessoas.

Comment: Tendo em vista que o nome do doador aparecerá 1 vez por cada 10 reais que doar. Da pra entender? Não sei se me expressei bem

Comment: Então edite novamente a pergunta e coloque tudo isso lá. No código atual não está claro que era para colocar vários nomes.

Comment: @hkotsubo foi mal :( editei novamente.

Comment: Ah, e se o valor for 25? 32? 49? Vai arredondar? Ou você só aceita os valores múltiplos de 10 (como 10, 20, 30, etc)?

Comment: @hkotsubo Os valores serão (10, 20, 30).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quando você faz `[ algo ]`, está criando uma lista (por causa dos `[ ]`), com um único elemento (`algo`).

No seu caso, esse `algo` é `nome * 3`, que basicamente é a string `nome` "multiplicada por 3". Em Python, quando você "multiplica" uma string por um número, o resultado é outra string, com o seu conteúdo repetido várias vezes. Ou seja, se `nome` for a string "Samuel", então `nome * 3` será a string "SamuelSamuelSamuel".

Portanto, você está criando uma lista contendo apenas um elemento: uma string com o `nome` repetido várias vezes.

Se a ideia é criar uma lista com o mesmo nome várias vezes, você poderia fazer `[ nome ] * 3` (a lista `[ nome ]` contém o nome uma vez, e ao "multiplicar" a lista por um número, você cria uma lista com este elemento repetido várias vezes), que resulta em uma lista com 3 elementos (todos iguais a `nome`).

Outro ponto é que no final você adiciona esta lista em outra lista, mas não parece ser o que você quer.

O que teria que ser feito é ter uma única lista, e você insere somente nela. Algo assim:

```py
nomes = []

for _ in range(3): # lê 3 nomes (pode mudar para quantos precisar)
    # lê os dados e atualiza os nomes
    valor = int(input('Digite o valor que você deseja doar: '))
    nome = input('Qual o seu nome? ')
    total, resto = divmod(valor, 10)
    if resto == 0 and total > 0:
        print(f'Você vai concorrer {total} vez{"es" if total > 1 else ""}.')
        nomes.extend([ nome ] * total)
    else:
        print('valor inválido, deve ser múltiplo de 10 e maior que zero')

print(nomes)
```

Como os valores devem ser múltiplos de 10, usei [`divmod`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#divmod) para pegar o resultado da divisão por 10 e o resto desta divisão. Assim, se o resto não for zero, o valor é inválido.

Depois eu uso `[ nome ] * total` para criar a lista com o nome repetido várias vezes, e uso `extend` para adicionar esses elementos na lista `nomes`.

Coloquei em um *loop* para ler vários nomes, mas aí você pode adaptar de acordo.

---

Depois você pode embaralhar com `random.shuffle`, se quiser:

```py
from random import shuffle
shuffle(nomes)
```

Se bem que, para sortear um valor qualquer, bastaria usar `random.choice` (talvez nem precise embaralhar, já que `choice` vai escolher um item da lista aleatoriamente, e tanto faz em que posição eles estão):

```py
from random import choice
sorteado = choice(nomes)
```

Comment: Rapaiz, eu testei, mas não parece ser o que o cara descreveu, posso postar uma solução?

Comment: @Danizavtz Eu entendi que era isso. Se vc entendeu outra coisa, responde aí também :-)

Comment: @hkotsubo muito obrigado, consegui aprender bastante com a sua explicação. E se caso não for múltiplos de 10, é só eu retirar o divmod?

Comment: @hkotsubo, publiquei a minha, vou colocar as referências da lib.

Comment: @SamuelTeixeira Se não for para aceitar somente múltiplos de 10 (e sim qualquer valor), aí depende de como seria a lógica. Mas você poderia fazer, por exemplo, `total = valor // 10` (com duas barras, o que já arredonda para baixo, ou seja, valores de 20 a 29 daria um total de `2`), e não precisaria testar o `resto`. Ou vc pode usar `valor / 10` (com uma barra) e usar alguma função do [módulo `math`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html) (como `ceil` ou `floor`) para arredondar de acordo com o que vc precisa

Comment: @hkotsubo muito obrigado, meu querido. você me ajudou demais!!!!!!!

Answer (score 1):

Uma maneira de resolver este problema é inserindo as pessoas diretamente em um array e depois fazer o sorteio.

Segue um exemplo:

```
from random import choice

def inserirNoSorteio(lista, nome, qtd):
    for i in range(qtd):
        lista.append(nome)
    return lista


repetir = True nomes = []

while repetir:
    valor = int(input('Digite o valor que você deseja doar: '))
    nome = input('Qual o seu nome? ')

    if valor < 20:
        total = 1
        inserirNoSorteio(nomes, nome, total)
        print('{} vai concorrer {} vezes.'.format(nome, total))
    elif valor < 30:
        total = 2
        inserirNoSorteio(nomes, nome, total)
        print('{} vai concorrer {} vezes.'.format(nome, total))
    else:
        total = 3
        inserirNoSorteio(nomes, nome, total)
        print('{} vai concorrer {} vezes.'.format(nome, total))
    
    
    inserirMaisPessoas = input('Deseja adicionar mais pessoas? (s/n)')
    if inserirMaisPessoas[0].lower() == 'n':
        repetir = False
     print('Sorteando o ganhador...') sorteado = choice(nomes) print(nomes) print('O ganhador foi: {}'.format(sorteado))
```

### Explicando o código

Em meu exemplo utilizei a função choice do modulo [`random`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html) do Python. Esta função vai retornar um elemento aleatório de uma lista não vazia. Caso a lista esteja vazia é lançado o erro  `IndexError`.

Minha lógica é baseada no código que foi fornecido, mas eu fiz algumas suposições em relação aos valores que o usuário pode doar. Por exemplo: se eu doar valores menores que 20, sempre vou adicionar o nome 1x, se for maior ou igual a 20, faço a inserção na lista do sorteio 2x, caso seja maior que 30 apenas 3x, então se o usuário doar 50, o nome dele será inserido 3x.

Para isso deixamos o usuário em um loop de inserção de doação e nome.

Após o usuário não querer mais inserir pessoas no sorteio é feito o sorteio com as pessoas da lista.
Estou exibindo o array de nomes (pessoas no sorteio), apenas para propósito de debug.

Comment: É verdade, possui um bug. @hkotsubo

Comment: @hkotsubo, corrigido.

Answer (score 0):

**Usando List Comprehensions (Compreensão de Listas)**

```
lista = ['Bia']

#considerando que cada nome custe 10

valor = input('Valor que deseja doar: ')
qtde = int((int(valor) / 10))
nome = input('Qual o seu nome? ')

#Commpressão de lista(List comprehension)
#Vale a pena dar uma pesquisada sobre o assunto mas adianto que usando LC existe uma 
#melhora de perfomance consideravel, fora o código limpo.

listaTemporaria = [nome for x in range(qtde)]
lista.extend(listaTemporaria) # equivalente a -> lista = lista + listaTemporaria

print(lista)
```

Answer (score 0):

De forma simplista, fica uma dica mais dinâmica de criar este sorteio:

```
valor = int(input('Digite o valor que você deseja doar: '))
nome = input('Qual o seu nome? ')
nomes = []
valor //= 10  # Equivalente à valor = valor // 10, que no caso retorna a parte inteira da divisao
[nomes.append(nome) for _ in range(valor)]
print("Voce vai concorrer a {} sorteio(s)".format(valor))
print(nomes)
```

Resultado alcançado:

```
Digite o valor que você deseja doar: 32
Qual o seu nome? Samuel
Voce vai concorrer a 3 sorteio(s)
['Samuel', 'Samuel', 'Samuel']
```